# Using Django, how would I generate a Tumblr-style series of date-ordered pages of different objects?

Tags: sql, django, tumblr

I have a Django app with classes for different things such as Post, Quote, Image, Link, etc. Like items in Tumblr. Each of these objects has a datetime.

I want to display a combined list of the 20 most recent items of all types. And I want to be able to page back through older items. ie, just like Tumblr's pages.

But I can't think how to do queries like this across many different types of object... Would I have to create a separate class, something like:

```
class CombinedItem(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    item_type = models.CharField() # eg, 'post', 'quote', 'image', 'link'
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
```

And add a new entry to that whenever I add a new Post, Quote, Image, etc. And then, for my list, query that CombinedItem class for the most recent items, and then fetch the main details for each item it returns? If so, what's the most efficient way of doing all that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to actually work in reverse. Each of those is a type of user-generated content, so they should all inherit from a common base:

```
class ContentItem(models.model):
    # common fields here

class Post(ContentItem):
    # post specific fields

....
```

Then, you can simply query the base model `ContentItem` and get a list of everything.

The only potential issue is that the results are `ContentItem`s and not `Post`s, `Quote`s, etc. However, in Django's implementation of MTI (multi-table inheritance), the child class is an attribute on the parent class. So a "Post" `ContentItem` will have a `.post` attribute from which you can access the `Post`. You can combine this with `hasattr` to create utility methods that you can use in your view. For example:

```
class ContentItem(models.Model):
    ...
    def is_post(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'post')
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% if content_item.is_post %}
    <!-- do some post-specific rendering here -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks, and very handy examples! I guess I'll either end up with a lot of joins, or else a query for every item in the list... But that's probably unavoidable however I do this. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes the "child" attributes are essentially reverse relationships, and `select_related` doesn't follow those. However, when Django 1.4 hits, the new `prefetch_related` should be able to select everything in one go. In the meantime, you can also check out django-batch-select, which basically implements the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this would be to create a generic Model called Item (or CombinedItem if you prefer) and make several models (Post, Quote, Image, etc.) that inherit from it. Django was designed with model inheritance in mind, and your specific need is covered by a feature called [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

Using this technique, you database would have different tables for Items, Posts, Quotes, etc. from which you could run individual queries.

Comment: Thanks Antoine, I should have thought of that - I can tell I've been away from Django for a while. I marked Chris Pratt's as the answer because of the extra examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GenericForeignKey[1], which will generate almost the same structure as what you have described.

The biggest difference is that the item_type field will actually be a foreign key into the contenttypes table, which Django automatically maintains.

Unfortunately, the standard ORM filter() methods won't work on that field. You'll have to query the models individually for their date ranges.

Alternately, you could combine a generic foreign key with a denormalised last-modified-timestamp field, which you update whenever the related object changes, and then you can query very quickly against that field, and pull out the related objects for your top-20 list when you need them.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: Thanks Ian. An interesting option, but Multi Table Inheritance looks like it might be the way to go.